# NodeJs Multidimensional Array - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array, socket.io

I am trying to change the value of an element in a Multidimensional array (9 rows, each row has 9 elements, each element is a array of 4 elements) using dynamic indexes i,j but I am getting the error "Cannot read property '8' of undefined" where 8 is the value of i . If I replace i,j with some fixed numbers like 1,2 then there is no error. Note that the variable cellid will be a two digit number like 11,12...19 , 21,22....29 , 91,92....99 . I am extracting the corresponding index values i and j using that number.

```
io.on("connect", (socket) =>{
console.log("socket id" + socket.id);
socket.on("inputnum", inputnum => {
    const issuccess = dotask(inputnum, socket.id);
    if(issuccess)
        socket.emit("inputnumchanged", object)
})
}



function dotask(inputnum, socketid){
var cellid = null;
object.highlightedcell.forEach(e => {
    if(e.clientid == socketid)  
        cellid = e.cellid;
})
if(!cellid)
    return null; //no cell was selected
const i= cellid/10 -1 , j= cellid%10 -1;
object.initialarray[i][j][2] = inputnum;
return 1;
}
```

This is how the object 'object' looks like

```
{ initialarray: [


 [
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 9, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 2, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 5, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 3, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 9, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 7, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 8, 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ]
  ]
], 
highlightedcell : [], 
inputnum : {inputnum: null, inputterid : null},
correctcount : 0,
requiredcorrect : 81-43,
issolved : 0

}
```

Here is a screenshot of error from the console.
[image: screenshot of error from console]

Comment: There is a typo in the question.  " "Cannot read property '8' of undefined" where 8 is the value of i  " . 8 is not the value of 'i' rather it is the value of 'j'

Answer (score 0):

I got help from one of my collegemates. In the line " const i= cellid/10 -1 , j= cellid%10 -1; " i would become a floating number and not a whole number . That is the problem. I took ceiling for i and the issue is solved.